# Android Studio is Not Resolving the Maven Repository AAR Files , Class Files are not available

Tags: aar

When I try to Add AAR Dependency in the repository in Maven gradle, the Files are not resolved and Class Files are not available in the External Libraries, when I Inspect the code, only the BuildConif is available, how to overcome this issue?

But the issue is Specific to the machine, the same works fine in other machines.